# Need to check RDS diskspace utilization

Tags: amazon-rds

Recently we have been facing problem on RDS as our allocated diskspace is getting exhausted on Amazon RDS.

So is there any tool/plugins (nagios plugin) available or any other utility through which we can monitor RDS Disk utilization?

P.S: We know cloudwatch can do this, but we are looking for other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this check_cloudwatch plugin to grab any cloudwatch metric so it can graphed in our private cloud using PNP4Nagios and Graphite, works very well.

[check_cloudwatch on github](https://github.com/j3tm0t0/check_cloudwatch)

Comment: Thanks Gingernator007.. will try this plugin and see if it can monitor  rds utilization :)

Answer (score 1):

I use aws cloud watch to monitor my rds instance's free space and cpu utilization. You can set up email alerts based on thresholds say when freespace < 25 GB. Like freespace there are variety of things you can monitor like R/W latency, DB connections, etc. You can find the steps (both via UI and cli) to setup cloud watch here.
[aws cloud watch setup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html)